# What are these theta functions appearing in Sloane's database

Tags: special-functions, modular-forms

Looking at Sloane's database, I found a neat formula for the lambda-invariant.
Let $q:\tau \mapsto \exp(\pi i \tau)$ on the complex upper-half plane. Then

$$\lambda(q) = 16q\;\prod_{k>0} \frac{(1 + q^{2k})^8}{(1 + q^{2k - 1})^8} = \frac{\vartheta_2(q)^4}{\vartheta_3(q)^4}.$$

What are those theta functions?

I found this formula [here](http://oeis.org/A115977).

Comment: What/who is Sloane?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html, I guess

Comment: @Jeroen: Neil Sloane is OEIS's maintainer.

Comment: If you need a pile of these coefficients, [Wolfram Alpha can handle that.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BSeriesCoefficient%5BInverseEllipticNomeQ%5Bq%5D%2C+%7Bq%2C+0%2C+k%7D%5D%2C+%7Bk%2C+0%2C+50%7D%5D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are [Jacobi theta functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) (with $z=0$)

$$\vartheta_2(q)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} q^{(n+1/2)^2}, \qquad \vartheta_3(q)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} q^{n^2}$$

Comment: To elaborate a bit: there are four kinds. The second and the third one are what figure into the expression of the modular lambda function.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician: We can cheat a bit and use the 4th one as well using, $$\left(\frac{\vartheta_2(q)}{\vartheta_3(q)}\right)^4+\left(\frac{\vartheta_4(q)}{\vartheta_3(q)}\right)^4 = 1$$ hence $$\lambda(q) =1-\left(\frac{\vartheta_4(q)}{\vartheta_3(q)}\right)^4 $$